# Microsoft Dynamics 2013 OnChange Script For Lookup Field

Tags: onchange, lookup, microsoft-dynamics

I'm currently working in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013. I'm trying to get a script to run on the OnChange event of a lookup field and it is not working. I noticed that when you make a selection, even when a script is not bound, it kind of refreshes the page and takes you back to the top. Any ideas?

```
function currentlyAssignedOnChange() {
         alert ("TEST ON CHANGE FIRING 3!!!"); 
         var dateAssigned = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_dateassigned");   
         dateAssigned.setValue(new Date());
         if (dateAssigned.getIsDirty()) {
             dateAssigned.setSubmitMode("always");
             Xrm.Page.data.entity.save(); 
          } 
 }
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide example code you are using?

Comment: This is the code. The thing is that when I call it from another field that doesn't do the refresh of the page, it works:

function currentlyAssignedOnChange()
{
 alert ("TEST ON CHANGE FIRING 3!!!");
 var dateAssigned = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_dateassigned");
 dateAssigned.setValue(new Date());
 if (dateAssigned.getIsDirty()) {
  dateAssigned.setSubmitMode("always");
        Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
 }
}

Comment: I think it has to do with that page refresh that takes place on change of the field. The script itself works if I call it from another field.

Comment: @der_michael Siddique Mahsud - Below are links to the properties of the field that I'm trying this with. Not sure if it will help: 

[1](http://spinyourwebconsulting.com/images/1.jpg)
[2](http://spinyourwebconsulting.com/images/2.jpg)
[3](http://spinyourwebconsulting.com/images/3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So the field in question was the "Assigned To" field. This field had a workflow associated with it that seemed to be blocking the script. I decided to just add the logic to the workflow instead.